# in which framework i can call a another page from staying in index or home page using get method type?

Tags: php

Actually i m new in php framework...

I just work to do there are one file which show as a home or index page. then i can call another page staying the same page like get method type. Please see the following example to clear you more..

Suppose
`www.name.com:1001/admin.php?action=admins-index` (this is home page)

and then:
`www.name.com:1001/admin.php?action=clients-list` (this is show another page)

is there anyone to help me to do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the query parameter

```
$param = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : '';
switch( $param ) {
    case 'admins-index':
         // < execute your code for admin index >
    break;
    case 'clients-list':
         // < execute your code for clients list >
    break;
    default:
         // < your code for any other value >
    break;
}
```